# Kusto query to view DNS servers in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to query the custom DNS servers that are configured in Azure VNETs across all VNETs, I am not sure if I am close, or far off... This is what I have so far :

```
 resources  
 | where type == "microsoft.network/virtualnetworks"
 | where properties['dhcpOptions']['dnsServers'][0] == "*"
 | summarize count () by 'dnsServers'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources  
| where type == "microsoft.network/virtualnetworks"
| project name, tostring(properties.dhcpOptions.dnsServers)
```